# Unhackable AWS S3 Public Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I want to create an S3 bucket

Rules:

1. All users over the internet can access the objects in bucket only if they have the complete path to the object, No access to directory structure and listing items in the directory
2. Only one IAM User will have read, write, list and delete access to the bucket
3. Other all users will have read access only if they know complete path to object and no write or list access.

How do I achieve this in best possible secure way ? Such that no hacker can insert/edit/delete the data in my bucket

What should my bucket permission settings looks like (Block Public Access Setting)?

What should my bucket policy look like ?

What should my IAM User policy look like ?

What if I create another IAM user in same aws account with the same policy ? will this IAM user have access to edit, insert, delete

What if I create another IAM user in different aws account with the same policy ? will this IAM user have access to edit, insert, delete

Comment: It would be good if you add some example or work done so far

Comment: Have you tried to read up documentation S3 public access and IAM? I think there might be exact examples of what you want

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you could start with this policy and try to modify it to add all your clauses.
In this policy, the deletion actions are only allowed to the root user of the account. 
So add the list and write action too so only the root user can do these actions.

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "Policy1588186664547",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "Stmt1588186644754",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:DeleteBucket",
                "s3:DeleteBucketPolicy",
                "s3:DeleteBucketWebsite",
                "s3:DeleteObject",
                "s3:DeleteObjectTagging",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersion",
                "s3:DeleteObjectVersionTagging"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::testpolycy4/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::testpolycy4"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringNotEquals": {
                    "aws:userid": "102345678910"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer to your questions :

- What should my bucket permission settings looks like (Block Public
  Access Setting)?

**BLOCKED all**

- What should my bucket policy look like?

**Modify that policy until obtaining your desired policy.**

I think you don't need an IAM policy, just with the bucket policy you can restrict the access to the object and allow just the users that you want to.

The tough part is the way to just allow access to the user if they have the full path, I think you can do this with the policy or a lambda function, but I'm not sure about this point.